# Java regex for HTML "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> " parsing

Tags: java, html, regex

I am new to regexps, can someone help me in getting a regex for parsing the tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

with all the possiblities?

Comment: TAG <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: **All** the possibilities? Don't try to do this with a regular expression. You can get away with them for HTML that fits a template, but for generic parsing, you need a real HTML parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @David @Reid Since <meta only occurs in the (non-nested) header, it actually can be parsed by regular expressions

Comment: A meta that specifies the character encoding *should* only occur once.

Comment: @David Dorward Precisely, and regular expressions are therefore as applicable as searching for the string "<meta ..."

Comment: My point was that "should" and "will" are not the same thing, I have stumbled across documents with multiple, contradictory encoding declarations. (And that's just limiting this to `<meta>`, if you actually want to figure out what the encoding of a document is, then there are half a dozen places you need to look.)

Comment: @phihag still, there are endless variations in case, in attribute order, in other attributes....

Answer (score 2):

To cover "all the possibilities", you really should be using HTML 5's [Determining the character encoding](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding) rules. These aren't expressible as a regular expression.

There is an open source [Java implementation of it in validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/)

---

If you insist on using a regular expression, then this will probably cover most cases where the encoding it declared with a meta element (it won't, for instance, cover XML declarations). It is however, dirty, makes some assumptions that are usually (but may not always be) right and I do not recommend it.

```
/<meta[^>]+charset=['"]?(.*?)['"]?[\/\s>]/i
```